# What is the list of trace sources supplied by the .Net framework?

Tags: .net, trace

.Net defines a "Trace Source" concept, allowing configuration files to specify which trace sources to listen for messages on. WCF provides several trace sources, and I would presume that other portions of the .Net Framework BCL publish other trace sources as well. What is the list of trace source names published to by the BCL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not including WPF and WWF, I'm seeing:

- "System.Net"
- "System.Net.HttpListener"
- "System.Net.Sockets"
- "System.Net.Cache"
- "System.Runtime.Serialization.CodeGeneration"
- "System.ServiceModel.OperationInvoker.CodeGeneration"
- "System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging"

And one for VB.NET's My.Application.Log

Note that these are trace source names, not class names.  You can use Red Gate's Reflector to find this yourself.

Comment: Hans, how did you find this list?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What did you look for? Uses of the `TraceSource` constructor?

Answer (score 10):

Some More (includes Hans answer):

- CardSpace
- Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge
- System.Activities
- System.Activities.Core.Presentation
- System.Activities.DurableInstancing
- System.Activities.Presentation
- System.ComponentModel.Composition
- System.IdentityModel
- System.IO.Log
- System.Net
- System.Net.Cache
- System.Net.Http
- System.Net.HttpListener
- System.Net.Sockets
- System.Net.WebSockets
- System.Runtime
- System.Runtime.Serialization
- System.Runtime.Serialization.CodeGeneration
- System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml
- System.ServiceModel
- System.ServiceModel.Activation
- System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging
- System.ServiceModel.OperationInvoker.CodeGeneration
- System.ServiceModel.Routing
- System.Transactions
- System.Web.Services.Asmx
- System.Windows.Data
- System.Windows.DependencyProperty
- System.Windows.Documents
- System.Windows.Freezable
- System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost
- System.Windows.Markup
- System.Windows.Media.Animation
- System.Windows.NameScope
- System.Windows.ResourceDictionary
- System.Windows.RoutedEvent
- System.Windows.Shell
- System.Workflow.Activities
- System.Workflow.Activities.Rules
- System.Xaml.Hosting

Comment: Also: System.Net.Http, System.Net.WebSockets, System.Workflow.Activities, System.Workflow.Activities.Rules, System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging (source: Reflector)

Comment: Thanks. Added them to the answer. Also, I alphabetized the list and made it a community wiki.